# What was the mass of the Viking sounding rocket engine (XLR-10-RM-2)?

Tags: engines, vanguard

I can find information about the XLR-10 for its sea level & vacuum thrust and specific impulse but not about its mass.

[image]

What did this thing mass? Was it gimballed?

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer: it was indeed gimballed.

[image]

From the typically excellent Drew Ex Machina [article.](https://www.drewexmachina.com/2019/05/03/americas-first-space-rocket-the-origin-first-flights-of-the-viking-rocket/)